# Regular expression that allow dots between numbers

Tags: javascript, php, regex, preg-match

I need some help to build a RegEx that match numeric values and allow also one dot between numbers, example of valid match:

```
25.23.25
25.2323.5656.5656
25
```

Example of invalid match:

```
.25.23.25
25.2323.5656.5656.
25.
25.
```

Can any give me some help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
^\d+(?:\.\d+)*$
```

This should do it.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/oE6jJ1/19